# Parsing issue after fetching json payload

Tags: javascript

I have a test endpoint api that delivers simple json payload like:

```
[{"startDate": "2021-1-1", "endDate": "2021-2-1"}]
```

I do fetch it in JavaScript like this:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/test')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('Request Failed', err));
```

Works fine, but the date presented as string in console.log like:

```
{startDate: "2021-1-1", endDate: "2021-2-1"}
```

I have another JavaScript code:

```
var keyVal = function (key, value) {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
        return new Date(value);
    }
    return value;
}

var json = '[{"startDate": "2021-1-1", "endDate": "2021-2-1"}]';
console.log(JSON.parse(json, keyVal));
```

This works fine, and the date presented as object in console.log like which my wanted goal:

```
{startDate: Mon Jan 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), endDate: Mon Feb 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)}
```

Now I tried to use it with my fetch method and have tried to do it this way:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/test')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        console.log(json)
        console.log(JSON.parse(json, keyVal));
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('Request Failed', err));
```

The first gives this result:

```
[{"startDate": "2021-1-1", "endDate": "2021-2-1"}]
```

But the second with JSON parse return this error:

```
Request Failed SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at index-api.html:48
```

I have also console log json and it is like

What is I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: `JSON.parse('[{"startDate": "2021-1-1", "endDate": "2021-2-1"}]',function (key, value) { if (typeof value === 'string') { return new Date(value); } return value; })` has the desired result for me. Are you sure you have the right `json` value?

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure all data is validated correctly

Comment: I can replicate your error with my one-liner only by editing the first argument to `JSON.parse` from the string you gave to something with an `o` as the second character. I can't replicate by changing the second argument

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ your solution did also worked for me, but I found luke answer is useful. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to parse as JSON an object that has already been parsed as JSON.

I can reproduce the same error as you by running any of the following:

```js
JSON.parse(JSON.parse("{}"));
JSON.parse({});
JSON.parse("[object Object]");
```

The first argument to `JSON.parse()` should be a string, but in the code `JSON.parse(json, keyVal)` you are passing it an object.  This object will get converted to the string `[object Object]` before `JSON.parse()` attempts to parse it.  This string is of course not valid JSON and will generate the error you are getting.

Instead, try passing the `.text()` of the response to `JSON.parse()`:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/test')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => {
        console.log(text)
        console.log(JSON.parse(text, keyVal));
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('Request Failed', err));
```